# Import txt file with data separated by columns and empty rows

Tags: python, import, delimiter, txt

I have a txt file with 3 columns of float numbers that needs to be imported but it needs to be separated by columns and empty rows.

For example, the txt file data looks like

```
1.0    1.1    1.2
1.3    1.4    1.5

2.0    2.1    2.2
2.3    2.4    2.5
```

I need the data to be imported to python like

```
column 1-1: 1.0, 1.3
column 2-1: 1.1, 1.4
column 3-1: 1.2, 1.5

column 1-2: 2.0, 2.3
column 2-2: 2.1, 2.4
column 3-2: 2.2, 2.5
```

I was able to import the txt file and separate by column using
`a,b,c = np.loadtxt('file.txt', dtype=float, unpack=True)`
but this method does not read the empty rows and I cannot further separate the data by empty rows.

EDIT: One main issue is loading the txt file while keeping the empty rows. Both `pandas.read_csv()` & `numpy.loadtxt()` remove the empty rows when importing.

Comment: numpy will just ignore blank lines like this ... do you need numpy?

Comment: Unless numpy is necessary, then use [https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp](python's file library) to keep the spaces. If there is a separator (such as \t) then it would be simple to write code to read the file.

Comment: @Jordan i don't think it's a case of not knowing how to open the file, i think they just wanted the fastest way of doing so, considering the fact that we're dealing with data science, this files could be massive, like petabytes level massive. in that case, it makes sense to try and find a better algorithm for this. i still think the best option is to just make an algorithm for this and just waiting the extra hour or two, it doesn't matter that much

Comment: @JoranBeasley I don't need to use numpy.

Comment: @oriraisfeld Correct, I can open the file and I want an automated way to separate the data. It's not petabyte size, but there are well over 1000 data points.

Answer (score 0):

so why not just make your own algorithm for it? it seems to me much easier then to configure numpy a certain way or get a module for it. i had to spend 5 minutes thinking and making an algorithm for this

```
def parse_file(file_data):
    all_numbers = []
    current_number = ""
    current_number_group: list[float] = []
    for letter in file_data:
        if letter == "\n":
            all_numbers.append(current_number_group)
            current_number_group = []
        elif letter == " " and current_number != "":
            current_number_group.append(float(current_number))
            current_number = ""
        elif letter != " ":
            current_number += letter
    
    if current_number != "":
        current_number_group.append(float(current_number))
    return all_numbers
```

this algorithm doesn't use numpy (i am using an online interpreter rn, so i can't install packages) and it's also very slow, so it would be even better for you to make your own version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import pandas as pd

text = """\
1.0    1.1    1.2
1.3    1.4    1.5

2.0    2.1    2.2
2.3    2.4    2.5"""


all_data = []
for group in map(str.strip, text.split("\n\n")):
    all_data.append(list(zip(*[line.split() for line in group.splitlines()])))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Col1        Col2        Col3
0  (1.0, 1.3)  (1.1, 1.4)  (1.2, 1.5)
1  (2.0, 2.3)  (2.1, 2.4)  (2.2, 2.5)
```

Comment: For this method, I cannot manually type in the data. The actual data has well over 1000 data points.

Comment: @DOMINICHERNANDEZ Don't type the data, open a file and read the contents of the file to the variable `text`

Comment: When I import the data file the empty rows are removed.  I think this would work if I could keep the empty rows when importing.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it with stdlib itself if you want:

```py
from itertools import groupby

text = """\
1.0    1.1    1.2
1.3    1.4    1.5

2.0    2.1    2.2
2.3    2.4    2.5"""

result: list[list[tuple[float, ...]]] = []

for k, grouped_lines in groupby(text.splitlines(), key=lambda x: bool(x.strip())):
    if k:
        floatted_grouped_lines = (map(float, line.split()) for line in grouped_lines)
        result.append(list(zip(*floatted_grouped_lines)))

for i, row in enumerate(result, start=1):
    print(f"row{i}: {row}")
```

output:

```
row1: [(1.0, 1.3), (1.1, 1.4), (1.2, 1.5)]
row2: [(2.0, 2.3), (2.1, 2.4), (2.2, 2.5)]
```

I used `groupby` to group the rows between empty lines. Then for each line in the group, I turned them in to a list of float numbers instead of a string. Now to convert:

```
[1.0, 1.1, 1.2], [1.3, 1.4, 1.5]
```

to

```
(1.0, 1.3) (1.1, 1.4) (1.2, 1.5)
```

You need to `zip()` them.